# AntiSamy style attribute in .NET

Tags: .net, antisamy

I am using AntiSamy in a .Net project. I would like to leave the style attributes for the `<span>` tags, intact. I tried to modify the policy but anything I do, i get the same result... From this:

```
<p><span style="font-size:10px"><span style="font-family:arial">Name here<br />
```

To this:

```
<p><span style=""><span style="">Name here<br />
```

After looking through the policy file i saw this comment there:

```
<!-- the "style" attribute will be validated by an inline stylesheet scanner, so no need to define anything here - i hate having to special case this but no other choice -->
```

Here i have some questions...

What does this commented line in the policy xml file mean?

Do i have to make changes for the style attribute in the `<common-attributes>` or this doesn't touch the style attributes in the `<span>` tags?

Do i have to make the change only in the `<tag name="span" action="validate"/>` under the `<tag-rules>` for the style attribute content to be intact?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "style" attribute  is a special case in AntiSamy (as value of style attribute consists of a list of property-value pairs).

```
style="font-size:10px; color:red;"
```

The value of style attribute is scanned by special scanner *an inline stylesheet scanner*. This validation is not trivial as for other tag attributes, as each property in the "style" itself should follow some rules. A section has to be defined for these rules  For example,

```
<css-rules>
    <property name="font-size" >
        <category-list>
            <category value="visual" />
        </category-list>
        <literal-list>
            <literal value="inherit" />
        </literal-list>
        <regexp-list>
            <regexp name="length" />
        </regexp-list>
    </property>
</css-rules>
```

The css property font-size will be validated against the rules defined in the css-rules. Here the regular expression length is defined in the common regular expressions section as

```
<regexp name="length"
            value="((-|\+)?0|(-|\+)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)(em|ex|px|in|cm|mm|pt|pc))" />
```

There is no change in common-attributes or tag-rules section.

Comment: I have that same configuration, what is not clear to me is what I should change to make it work?